# host pings ok, but its nameserver wouldn't ping

Tags: domain-name-system

I run DNS server and host few websites (example - `tvdish.tv`).

All websites run fine and its whois points to `ns1.projectinprogress.com` and `ns2.projectinprogress.com`.

However I can't ping `projectinprogress.com` anymore. It happened after my server was powered up yesterday (power outage in COLO4 Dallas data center).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, kudos for actually providing real domains.  It makes the diagnosis much easier.

Running http://squish.net/dnscheck over the record in question says:

```
50.0% of queries will end in failure at 72.249.119.162 (ns1.projectinprogress.com) - returned SERVFAIL code

50.0% of queries will end in failure at 72.249.119.163 (ns2.projectinprogress.com) - returned SERVFAIL code
```

I'm going to take a wild stab in the dark and guess that you've put both your DNS servers on the one machine, and now you've just learnt why that is a *phenomenally* bad idea.  There are whole RFCs dedicated to why that is a bad idea.

As to why your DNS server has suddenly decided to fail all queries, that's beyond me because you haven't provided any diagnostically relevant information on that aspect of things.  Take a stab at it yourself, but if you can't figure it out you'll need to provide your DNS server software, version, and relevant-looking log messages (but probably ask a separate question as it'll get too confusing in this one).

Comment: i got it that my DNS config is bad, i was just trying for now to figure out 
1.how is it possible that tvdish.tv is working while its nameservers wouldn't ping
2.what (theoretically) could cause it to stop working

Comment: 1. Because the glue records mean that the resolver is never actually authoritatively resolving the nameservers; 2. Lots of things, that's why you should ask a question with what server you're using and your logs, like I said *in my answer*.